# Range is filling up with hidden row values, not sure why

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fill a range with a filtered column of dynamic length. At this moment, after filtering, my column is 179 rows (total row count is >25000). When I print range.rows.count, it shows, correctly, that it has 179 values. but when I print each value using a for loop, it includes values that are hidden. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
LR = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("O2:O" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Here's the code I use to view what it contains:

```
For x = 1 To rng.Count
  Debug.Print rng.Cells(x, 1).Value
Next x

Debug.Print x
```

Comment: Side note, `rng.Rows.Count` will only return the row count of the first *area*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the `Cells` (or `Range`) properties to a range doesn't restrict you to cells actually in that range, it merely provides an anchor point. You would be better off with a `For Each` loop like this:

```
For Each cell in rng.Cells
  Debug.Print cell.Value
Next cell
```